# how to catch file or dir from a certain dir in php

Tags: php, realpath

I am trying to catch (echo) a file or directory from a certain directory.

I want to bind it to a variable.

No i am experiencing with realpath and he gives me the exact file location but from the server.

```
echo realpath($dir.'/'.$file);
```

So my echo shows me this:
`/home/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/develop3/httpdocs/uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/Jellyfish.jpg`
or `/home/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/develop3/httpdocs/uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/nameofdirectory`

it should be this:

`uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/Jellyfish.jpg`
and
 `uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/nameofdirectory`

How can i achieve that?

Comment: where does `$dir` come from ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: `$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID; `

Comment: I guess you should update your question with the full, or at least more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you really need and what is the value of `$dir`, but you can use:

```
$fullPath = realpath($dir.'/'.$file);
$relativePath = preg_replace('%/home.*httpdocs/%i', '', $fullPath);
```